# Why isn't AJAX $.post working in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've been killing myself trying to understand why $.post isn't working..
I'm trying to make two drops downs..

The first will contain the main category and the second drop down contains the sub categories for the first drop down..

```
[MAIN CATEGORY DROP DOWN] [SUB CATEGORY DROP DOWN]
```

The first drop down works flawlessly, but the sub categories just isn't fetching with ajax for some reason why I do not know..

```
add_shortcode( 'custom_query', 'custom_query' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_custom_query', 'getSubCategory' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_query', 'getSubCategory' );
function custom_query( $cat_id )
{       
    // first dropdown
    $first_dropdown = array( 'show_option_all'    => '','show_option_none'   => 'Select main category','orderby' => 'ID','order' => 'ASC','show_count' => 0,    'hide_empty' => 0, 'exclude' => 0,'echo' => 1,'selected' => 0,'child_of' => $cat_id,'hierarchical' => 1,'name' => 'chained-categories','id' => '','class' => 'postform',    'depth' => 1, 'tab_index' => 0,'taxonomy' => 'category', 'hide_if_empty' => false ); 
    wp_dropdown_categories( $first_dropdown );

    // subcategories empty but will be populated once the first main category is selected
    echo '<div id="chained-subcontainer">
            <select name="chained-subcategories" id="chained-subcategories">
                <option value="">- Select a category first -</option>
            </select>
        </div>';

    // javascript
    echo '  
        <script type="text/javascript">

            (function($)
            {
                var ajaxurl = "../../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
                var subdata = { action: "custom_query" };

                $("#chained-categories").change(function()
                {
                    subdata[ "chained_subcat_id" ] = $( this ).val();
                    subdata[ "chained_subcat_name" ] = $("#chained-categories option[value="+ $( this ).val() + "]").text();

                    if( $( this ).val() > 0 )
                    {
                        #this here works once the first cat is picked
                        alert($("#chained-categories option:selected").val());

                        $.post
                        (
                            ajaxurl, 
                            subdata,   
                            function( response )
                            {
                                $( "#chained-subcontainer" ).html( response );
                            }
                        );
                    } else {
                        $( "#chained-subcontainer" ).html( "<select name="chained-subcategories" id="chained-subcategories"><option value="">- Select a category first -</option></select>" );

                    }   
                });
            })(jQuery);

        </script>
    ';
}

function getSubCategory()
{
    $second_dropdown = array('show_option_all' => '', 'show_option_none' => 'Select subcategory','orderby' => 'ID', 'order' => 'ASC', 'show_count'  => 0, 'hide_empty' => 0, 'exclude' => 0, 'echo' => 1, 'selected' => 0, 'child_of' => $_POST[ 'chained_subcat_id' ], 'hierarchical' => 1, 'name'    => 'chained-subcontainer', 'id' => '', 'class'   => 'postform','depth' => 1, 'tab_index' => 0, 'taxonomy' => 'category', 'hide_if_empty' => false ); 
    wp_dropdown_categories( $second_dropdown );
}
```

I know for a fact that it's the $.post part that isn't working because I included an alert for once any option is selected in the first drop down it would show the value of it.. and it works, as long as the `$.post` part of the code isn't included..

EDIT: So after david's suggestion, I was able to check some piece of the code, while everything works just as expected.. as far as ajax working.. I've got a small problem..

In this line of code,

```
else {
    $("#chained-subcontainer").html("<select name="chained-subcategories" id="chained-subcategories"><option value="">Select a category first</option></select>");
}
```

If I leave that on, the code does not work as far as ajax.. if I remove that part, then ajax fetches the data correctly.. and I can't seem to understand why..this is what I get from JSHINT "`Expected ')' and instead saw 'chained'.`"

Comment: Is there an error on the browser console?  Is the AJAX request being made?  What is the server's response?  We can't debug this for you.

Comment: I understand.. you actually helped me out so much... I've only have one question left if you could take a look.. I'm going to update it.

Answer (score 0):

> If I leave that on, the code does not work as far as ajax

That's because you have a syntax error, so none of the JavaScript is going to work.

Notice the syntax highlighting here on Stack Overflow:

```
$( "#chained-subcontainer" ).html( "<select name="chained-subcategories" id="chained-subcategories"><option value="">- Select a category first -</option></select>" );
                                                 ^--- here
```

In this case, the easiest solution is simply to use single-quotes for your strings.  Since your strings don't themselves *contain* single-quotes (but *do* dontain double-quotes):

```
$( '#chained-subcontainer' ).html( '<select name="chained-subcategories" id="chained-subcategories"><option value="">- Select a category first -</option></select>' );
```

Any time a string contains a quote character, you have to ensure that the parser isn't going to interpret that character as being the end of the string.  Either by using different kinds of quotes or by "escaping" those quote characters.